# Using group_by() to group df by several variables, but it is clear that one of the variables is excluded from grouping

Tags: r

Here is a reproducible example:

```
set.seed(237582)
    df <- data.frame(outcome = sample(c(1,2), 10, replace = T), 
                      age = sample(seq(21,80), 10, replace = T),
                     AH = sample(c(1,0), 10, replace = T ), HSM = sample(c(1,0), 10, replace = T),
                     HNM = sample(c(1,0), 10, replace = T))

df <- as.data.frame(df) %>%  
  reshape::melt(id.vars = c("outcome", "age") , variable_name = "condition")
df %>% group_by(outcome, condition) %>% count()
```

The outcome of the code:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   outcome, condition [6]
  outcome condition     n
    <dbl> <fct>     <int>
1       1 AH            6
2       1 HSM           6
3       1 HNM           6
4       2 AH            4
5       2 HSM           4
6       2 HNM           4
```

As you can see, it groups only by outcome, but not by condition. What is the issue?

The expected result:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   outcome, condition [6]
  outcome condition     n
    <dbl> <chr>     <int>
1       1 AH            3
2       1 HNM           1
3       1 HSM           1
4       2 AH            1
5       2 HNM           2
6       2 HSM           2
>
```

I'd like to be able to show how many "1" there are per outcome and condition.

Comment: Could you be please more specific in what you consider not working as expected?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your example. You should specify the libraries used to run your code. Is it reshape2::melt that you are using?

Comment: @Jakub.Novotny Yes, that one.

Comment: @Jakub.Novotny You can see in the  code, that I grouped by outcome and condition, but the resulted count is given as if grouped only by outcome.

Comment: After running your code, there does not seem to be any condition column in your df.

Comment: @Jakub.Novotny Ok, when using reshape2 it ignores the argument variable_name, but even if I group by "variable" it still gives the same result. If I use reshape:: I get the column "condition", but again it doesn't do the grouping by the variable "condition", giving the same result no matter which library I choose.

Comment: Could you please edit your answer so that it does not result in an error, and also clearly state what the expected result is?

Comment: @Jakub.Novotny edited.

Comment: Please use `set.seed` to show the example

Comment: @akrun Ok, I added it.

Comment: @user18942 Based on the example showed, how are you getting the n as 2 for outcome 1 and condition AH.  I get 6 rows `df %>% filter(outcome == 1, condition == 'AH')`

Comment: Even the n of 3 is not clear.  I get only two 1s for that group

Answer (score 0):

If we need to get the number of 1's (as it in binary 'value' column), simply do a `sum`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(outcome, condition) %>% 
   summarise(n = sum(value), .groups = 'drop')
```

Or if there are other values as well, convert to logical and then do a `sum`

```
df %>% 
    group_by(outcome, condition) %>% 
    summarise(n = sum(value == 1), .groups = 'drop')
```

---

Or another option is to insert a `filter` before the `count`

```
df %>%
   filter(value == 1) %>%
   count(outcome, condition)
```

Note: We don't need a `group_by` and then `count`.  `count` would simply get the frequency